# Find the max diff between every element of two lists

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries and would like to find which state has the maximum difference for every element of the two lists. The length of the two lists is the same.

```
list1 = [{'NY':40, 'NJ':30, 'FL':30}, {'NY':40, 'NJ':50, 'FL':10}]

list2 = [{'NY':50, 'NJ':45, 'CT':20}, {'NY':40, 'FL':30}]
```

For `list1[0]` and `list2[0]`, `FL` has the maximum difference between the two since `FL` = 30, `NY` = 10, `NJ` = 15, and `CT` = 20. For `list1[1]` and `list2[1]`, `NJ` has the maximum difference.

How to get the desired output below? Thanks.

```
 State  Diff 
 FL     30
 NJ     50
```

Comment: Hi, ALollz, yes. The value is zero if the state is not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple iteration over two lists together using `zip` and keep track of maximum value in each iteration

```
res=[]
for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2):
    max_diff = tuple((0,0))
    for key in set(list(l1.keys()) + list(l2.keys())):
        diff = abs(l1.get(key,0) - l2.get(key,0)) 

        if diff > max_diff[1]:
            max_diff = tuple((key,diff))
    res.append((max_diff))
```

Output:

```
[('FL', 30), ('NJ', 50)]
```

Comment: @pault I know OP may have to convert it into a `list` in Python3. Updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 4):

We want to compare the corresponding rows of the two DataFrames. First, let's `align` them:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)    
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)   

df1, df2 = df1.fillna(0).align(df2.fillna(0), fill_value=0)
df1

   CT  FL  NJ  NY
0   0  30  30  40
1   0  10  50  40

df2
     CT    FL    NJ  NY
0  20.0   0.0  45.0  50
1   0.0  30.0   0.0  40
```

Now, you can use `idmax` to find the values with the largest difference, call `lookup` to get the diff value and create a new DataFrame.

```
u = (df1 - df2).abs()
idx = u.idxmax(1)
pd.DataFrame({'State': idx, 'Diff': u.lookup(u.index, u.idxmax(1))})

  State  Diff
0    FL  30.0
1    NJ  50.0
```

Comment: I was in the process of referring to your pandas merging 101 Q/A to sort out the syntax here.

Comment: @pault I'm happy to hear you're finding my QnA helpful :) Although in this particular case I'm not quite sure it'd help. . . :P

Comment: I was thinking make the columns the index and merge do and outer join, then calc the difference...I'm just really deep in spark right now so I think of everything as table joins.

Comment: @pault Ah, yes. I shorted that particular step using `align`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably go with the `pandas` approach, but you can also use a list comprehension here:

```
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter

max_diffs = [
    max(
        [
            (k, np.abs(a.get(k, 0) - b.get(k, 0))) 
            for k in set(list(a.keys()) + list(b.keys()))
        ], 
        key=itemgetter(1)
    ) 
    for a, b in zip(list1, list2)
]

print(max_diffs)
#[('FL', 30), ('NJ', 50)]
```

And if you wanted the output in a DataFrame, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(max_diffs, columns=["State", "Diff"])
print(df)
#  State  Diff
#0    FL    30
#1    NJ    50
```